# ResultSet missing getObject()

Tags: java, jdbc

when I add this dependency in Gradle,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.lazyluke:log4jdbc-remix:0.2.7'
}
```

found a problem in ResultSetSpy class,
Class 'ResultSetSpy' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getObject(int, Class)' in 'ResultSet'

this error is causing JDBC connection error with DB.
Does anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Use a library that works. This thing is 11 years old and appears to have been only experimental in the first place. [This link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-remix/) says it is dead.